# How to stop loop in flutter card swiper?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-slider

- I made slide learning app but slide was looping playing continuously
- I need to stop auto play it reaches the end.
- I'm using `card_swiper: ^1.0.2`
- I update my full code  is here
  -I'm also using a Assets audio player
- I try loop: false it won't work
- Thanks in advance

I don't know how to use it

```
  import 'package:assets_audio_player/assets_audio_player.dart';
import 'package:card_swiper/card_swiper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Chemistry extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChemistryState createState() => _ChemistryState();
}

class _ChemistryState extends State<Chemistry> {
  List images = [
    'assets/images/che/s.jpg',
    'assets/images/che/t.jpg',
    'assets/images/che/u.jpg',
    'assets/images/che/v.jpg',
    'assets/images/che/w.jpg',
    'assets/images/che/x.jpg',
    'assets/images/che/y.jpg',
    'assets/images/che/z.jpg',
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body:Swiper(
          itemCount: images.length,
          loop: false,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(27.0),
              child: Image.asset(
                images[index],
              ),
            );
          },
          indicatorLayout: PageIndicatorLayout.COLOR,
          onIndexChanged: (index) {
            playaudio(index);
          },
          autoplayDelay: 4000,
          autoplay: true,
          pagination: FractionPaginationBuilder(
              color: Colors.red, activeColor: Colors.green, fontSize: 10),
          // control: SwiperControl(),
        ),
      ),

    );
  }
}

void playaudio(index) async {
  AssetsAudioPlayer.newPlayer().open(
    Audio('assets/audio/Chemistry/a$index.mp3'),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set loop: false - to disable continuous loop mode.
If you want autoplay, then set autoplay: true

Comment: I already try this loop:false but again it looping

Comment: If you want to know how to use stopAutoplay(), then
1. You have to create a SwiperController. You can create it just like you create a normal TextEditingController. 

2. Then assign the controller to Swiper by its controller method.

3. Then you call it by swiperController.stopAutoPlay();

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation https://pub.dev/packages/card_swiper you can set loop attribute to false

```
 Swiper(
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context,int index){
      return Image.network("https://via.placeholder.com/350x150",fit: BoxFit.fill,);
    },
    itemCount: 3,
    loop:false,
    pagination: SwiperPagination(),
  ),
```

Comment: I already try this loop:false but again it looping

Comment: In the end of documentation I saw  that 'void stopAutoplay()'

Comment: remove control attribue then it stop looping.